# writing file & displaying result in idle

Tags: python, python-3.x

trying to process text file and would like to see output in idle as well as redirected to text file. due to text formatting, i need to keep statement in print function (end = ''). i am looking for a way to use "end = ''" and "file=output_file" simultaneously with print function.

```
import re
input_file = open ('E:\input.txt','r')
output_file = open ('E:\output.txt','w')

for line in input_file:
        if re.match('ab|cd', line):
                print ('line with ab or cd: ', end = '',file=output_file )
                print (line, end = '',file=output_file)
                print ('  --------', file=output_file)
                print ('  --------',file=output_file)
                print ('!',file=output_file)
        else:
                print (line,file=output_file)
```

Comment: My +1 for Sebastian's answer. Notice that it does contain but does not emphasize the replacement of `print` in the form `output_file.write('some string\nnext line')`. Do not forget `.close()` or use the `with`construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write to several places using a single `print()`, you could define a file-like object:

```py
class TeeFile(object):
    def __init__(self, *files):
        self.files = files
    def write(self, data):
        for f in self.files:
            f.write(data)
    def flush(self):
        for f in self.files:
            f.flush()
```

Example:

```py
import sys

file = TeeFile(sys.stderr, output_file)
print("abc", end="", file=file)
file.flush()
```